# Problema al crear JSONObject en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, json

Estoy creando un `login` en Android Studio guiándome de un tutorial pero he quedado atascado, al crear un `JSONObject` hay algo que falla y no sé que es. He logrado crear un `String` con el valor del `JSON` e intentado crear el JSON desde el `String` pero no ha dado resultados.

Pero si he logrado imprimir dicho `String` y si tiene los valores que solicito. Y no sé que sea ya que no me muestra ningún error con el cuál pueda investigar.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public void verificar(JSONObject datos)
{
    try
    {
        String jresultado = datos.getString("resultado");
        if (jresultado.equals("true"))
        {
            JSONObject jdatos = new JSONObject(datos.getString("datos"));
            String u = jdatos.getString("user");
            String p = jdatos.getString("pwd");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correcto Usuario: "+u+" / Pwd: "+p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(jresultado.equals("false"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error de conexion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException problema){problema.printStackTrace();}
}
```

NOTA:

Este es el contenido que lleva el `JSONObject` "datos":

```
{"resultado":"true","datos":[{"user":"user","pwd":"9003d1df22eb4d3820015070385194c8"}]}
```

`"datos"` que es un `JSONObject` si esta lleno ya que de el obtengo el valor de "resultado" pero se queda atorado al obtener el contenido de "datos"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que resultado es un `String` por lo cuál no tiene problemas, pero `datos` es un `array` entonces debería `parsear` a `JSONArray` y luego acceder a la posición que con `getJSONObject` y luego a la propiedad como lo hizo con resultado.

```
 JSONArray datos = data.getJSONArray("datos");

 System.out.println(datos.getJSONObject(0).getString("pwd"));
 System.out.println(datos.getJSONObject(0).getString("user"));
```

Puede que este `array` de datos tenga más de 1 elemento, entonces convendría iterar sobre el con un `for` simple quizá.

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < datos.length() ; i++){
    System.out.println(datos.getJSONObject(i).getString("pwd"));
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias... yo ya había probado con el JSONArray pero solo había tratado de obtener las variables así: datos.getString(0); y entonces me mostraba el contenido entero del array